# What are best practices for naming convention, hierarchy structure for shared drives?

Tags: terminology, sharing, files, organization, folders

I'm working on a project to organize a Google Drive used to share company folders and files.  I don't want to make changes for the sake of change.  I do want to base the changes on a well documented process that defines best practices, naming conventions, hierarchy structures, and management.  I want something that is scalable as the company grows.  Ideally the future state would be relatively easy to navigate and intuitive.  Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: No offense, but this question is vague. You can go with reporting structure, project names, functions, business units as your primary skeleton. It is very much subjective. It depends on the kind of data being stored, the frequency of access, the number of users accessing it, etc.

Comment: Structures and hierarchy of drives will be dependant on the particular data requirements of each individual/company